# I'm confused about model relationships in django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

ok, so I want to build a headless backend in Django and was running into issues as to how to best relate my models to achieve the desired result.

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to create the categories and then have them accessible as a selection to choose from when I want to ascribe them to a book or movie

the goal is to be able to create multiple categories and select/add the correct categories to the movie or book they best fit.
here's what I thought up but I don't know if I'm going to get the desired result but I think I'm missing a bit.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField() 
    description = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: These models look fine to me according to your description. One thing I would change is the fields name, it should be `categories` instead of `category`, since you can assign multiple of them to Book or Movie

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov thank you. just needed the reassurance cause I felt like I wasn't getting it. lol